# what is the meaning of &address

Tags: c++, pointers

I am learning C++ and pointers and have come across a weird observation. Take a look at this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void test(int *address) {
    cout << address << endl; //prints the same address again
    cout << &address << endl; // this address is different
}

int main() {
    int m = 22;
    cout << &m << endl; //prints some address
    test(&m);
    return 0;
}
```

basically I am using & on an address and printing it. The unexpected is that `&address` is different from `address`. What is the meaning of `&address`?

Comment: You should just name variable properly. For example `m` is some value, so name it `value`. Then it would be obvious that `&value` yields a pointer to value. `a` is not a value, it a pointer to value, so name it something like `pointer_to_value`. Then it will be obvious that `&pointer_to_value` is a pointer to pointer to value.

Comment: Pointers are variables too. References though... they are something different.

Comment: Maybe name a to address instead, to match the formatting from the rest of the question.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the meaning of `&address`?

It is the same as the meaning of `&m`, except for a different variable. `&` is the addressof operator, and `&address` is the memory address where the object named by the identifier `address` is stored. In the example, `&a` is where `a` is stored. Function arguments are local variables.

Furthermore, since `a` is a pointer to `int`, the type of pointer to `a` is pointer to pointer to `int` i.e. `int**`.

<sub>Although the example doesn't involve reference variables, note that when the operand of addressof operator is a reference, the result will be the address of the referred object. Reference variables are not objects and don't necessarily have a memory address at all.</sub>

Comment: "Reference variables are not objects and don't necessarily have a memory address at all."  Named variables, even if they are references, are lvalues and have memory addresses and you can take the address of them with `&`, Perhaps you meant expression values instead of variables?

Comment: @doug You can take an address from a reference with the addressof operator, but you won't get the address where the reference is stored; You get the address of the referred object. References don't necessarily have storage at all. If there is no storage, then there is no address for that storage.

Comment: Sure you do. If you take the address of a reference and use it, for instance as an argument to a function that takes a pointer, the object will be instantiated and an address to it will be provided. Of course if you take an address but don't use it for anything that requires the address it may not get instantiated in memory but that's true with pretty much all of C++ that doesn't produce side effects. Heck, for `int I=0; I doesn't necessarily have an address. Unless it's needed.

Comment: `and an address to it will be provided` and that address will be the one where the referred object is stored. From perspective of the abstract machine, all objects have storage. But indeed, if that fact has no observable effects, then a compiler does not need to realise that storage. Reference are not objects though, and you cannot observe their address directly.

Comment: `and you cannot observe their address directly.` Of course not. But once you take the address of a reference to it with the `&` operator, it does. Your answer strongly suggests you can't take the address of a such a reference when doing so will cause it to be instantiated if needed like taking the address of any other lvalue.

Comment: @doug `Your answer strongly suggests you can't take the address of a such a reference` Indeed. That's because when a reference is used as an operand of addressof operator, the result is always the address of the referred object; Not the address of the reference (which may but might not have storage).

Comment: Of course `&` returns the address of the referenced object of whatever category. I poorly used the word "reference" intending to refer to its referred object. My point was simply that taking the address of anything from another lvalue to a an expiring r value, through a reference always returns the actual object's address which is also what you are saying. I should have been clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a pointer to a pointer.

What it mean? It means we can alter a pointer passed to a function like so:

```
void test(int **a, size_t *n);
{
    *n = 4;
    *a = new int[4];
    a[0][0] = 123;
    a[0][1] = 64;
    a[0][2] = 32;
    a[0][3] = 16;
}

int main()
{
    size _t n; int *a;
    test (&a, &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << a[n] << endl;
    delete a;
}
```